# How do I update a large SQL table using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am building an etl using `pyspark` in `databricks`.

I have a source SQL table with roughly 10 million rows of data which I want to load into a SQL staging table.

I have two basic requirements:-

1. When a row is added to the source table, it must to inserted into the staging table.
2. When a row is updated to the source table, it must to updated into the staging table.

**Source data**

Thankfully the source table has two timestamp columns for created and updated time. I can query the new and updated data using these two columns and put it into a `dataframe` called source_df.

**Target data**

I load all the keys (IDs) from the staging table into a `dataframe` called target_df.

**Working out changes**

I join the two `dataframe` together based on the key to work out which rows already exist (which form updates), and which rows don't exist (which form inserts). This gives me two new `dataframes`, inserts_df and updates_df.

**Inserting new rows**

This is easy because I can just use inserts_df.write to directly write into the staging table. Job done!

**Updating existing rows**

This is what I can't figure out as there is little in the way of existing examples. I am lead to believe that you can't do updates using `pyspark`. I could use the "overwrite" mode to replace the SQL table, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to replace 10 million rows when I only want to update half a dozen.

How can I effectively get the rows from updates_df into SQL without overwriting the whole table?

Comment: Are you using Delta format?

Comment: No, but I don't see how using a Delta format would help anyway?

Comment: It's because delta tables enable MERGE operation (update/insert), avoiding overwrite all table

Comment: @Kafels I have searched for hours trying to find out how to "MERGE" from delta tables into SQL Server, but I cannot find any examples of this. Can you please share something which might help?

Comment: Databricks [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html)

Comment: How did you fix this issue?